# Understanding the conceptual basics of Distributed TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Let me describe the cluster setup first :

- I have two nodes (each with 2 GPUs). I refer to them as Node A and Node B
- Each node has its own SSD storage.
- [OAR](http://oar.imag.fr/docs/latest/user/commands/oarsub.html) is the cluster manager that is used.

I have gone through the Distributed TensorFlow documentation but there are some functional basics I could not understand properly and hence this question.

Consider the following situation :

- I have copied around 600 GB of data on Node A.
- I can use OAR to specifically ask for allocation of 4 GPUs across the two nodes.

If I want to use Distributed TensorFlow to train a model :

1. How do I specify network addresses to tf.train.ClusterSpec ? What are those network addresses ? In the documentation are names such as localhost:2222 the same names reserved for a particular node with the cluster manager ?
2. My data is copied to node A. During training will TensorFlow itself be responsible for sending this data as input to the GPU that is on node B ?
3. Will I need to manually create the TensorFlow Graph for each GPU on each node using tf.device() ?
4. If I also want to use some additional CPU nodes will I have to have their names beforehand and put them in the code ?

Answer (score 1):

2. Yes
3. Your client creates the graph and executes this graph on the worker. If you use between-graph replication as in the [howto](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/how_tos/distributed/index.html) with parameter server, your client and worker is the same process. This process only needs to create part of the graph for the current node using `with tf.device`. If you use within-graph replication with single client, your client needs to create graph for all nodes using multiple `with tf.graph` sections.

The simplest example of within-graph replication with separate client/worker processes is [here](https://gist.github.com/yaroslavvb/1124bb02a9fd4abce3d86caf2f950cb2)

4. You generally need to configure all the nodes ahead of time through cluster spec, and their names get assigned sequentially as `/job:worker/task:0`, `/job:worker/task:1` etc